# How to serialize object type to JSON in Scalatra?

Tags: json, scala, scalatra, json4s

I am a newbie in Scalatra. I have a servlet with JacksonJsonSupport which serves REST endpoint with list of objects.

```
class OperationsController extends MyappStack with JacksonJsonSupport {

  before() {
    contentType = formats("json")
  }

  get("/") {
    Data.operations
  }
}
```

The `Operation` is implemented by either `Adding` or `Removing` **case classes**. 
How do I add to the `GET /` response the specific class to the value? I would like to get as a response:

```
[
  {
     "operation": "Adding",
     "value": 100
  }
]
```

Instead of

```
[
  {
     "value": 100
  }
]
```

Where `Adding` is a class that extends `Operation`.

Comment: Does Adding or Removing have state? Can you make them case objects?

Comment: They are case classes of the Operation. `case class Adding extens Operation`. They don't have additional state parameter inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For polymorphic values json4s can add the concrete type as an additional field. This is called a "type hint":

```
[{
    "jsonClass": "Adding",
    "value": 10
}, {
    "jsonClass": "Adding",
    "value": 20
}, {
    "jsonClass": "Removing",
    "value": 20
}]
```

This is for example using the `ShortTypeHints`:

```
import org.json4s.{ShortTypeHints, DefaultFormats}
import org.scalatra.ScalatraServlet
import org.scalatra.json.JacksonJsonSupport
import org.scalatra.test.specs2.MutableScalatraSpec

sealed trait Operation
case class Adding(value: Int) extends Operation
case class Removing(value: Int) extends Operation

class json1 extends MutableScalatraSpec {

  mount(new ScalatraServlet with JacksonJsonSupport {

    def typeHints = new ShortTypeHints(List(
      classOf[Adding], classOf[Removing]
    ))

    implicit lazy val jsonFormats = DefaultFormats + typeHints

    before() {
      contentType = formats("json")
    }

    get("/") {
      List(
        Adding(10),
        Adding(20),
        Removing(20)
      )
    }

  }, "/*")

  "Should return a list of operations" in {

    get("/", headers = Seq("Content-type" -> "application/json")) {
      println(body)
      status should beEqualTo(200)
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, it looks promising

Answer (score 1):

I think, that the easiest way is to update your case classes like

```
case class Adding(value: Int, operation: String = "Adding") 
case class Removing (value: Int, operation: String = "Removing")
```

Another way is to update your jsonFormats with custom serializer, I found example of jsons custom serialization [here](https://gist.github.com/casualjim/5130756)

Comment: I am not interested in duplicating the information. This solution doesnt satisfy me, but thanks for the proposition

Answer (score 0):

json_conversion.scala file we created the trait SimpleMongoDbJsonConversion and we use this in MyScalatraServlet.scala file, see the example below.

**json_conversion.scala**

```
package com.example.app

import org.scalatra._
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

trait SimpleMongoDbJsonConversion extends ScalatraBase with ApiFormats {

  def renderMongo = {
    case dbo: DBObject =>
      contentType = formats("json")
      dbo.toString

    case xs: TraversableOnce[_] =>
      contentType = formats("json")
      val l = xs map (x => x.toString) mkString(",")
      "[" + l + "]"

  }: RenderPipeline

  override protected def renderPipeline = renderMongo orElse super.renderPipeline

}
```

**MyScalatraServlet.scala**

```
package com.example.app

import org.scalatra._
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

class MyScalatraMongoServlet(mongoColl: MongoCollection) extends MyScalatraWebAppStack with SimpleMongoDbJsonConversion {

  get("/") {
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        Say <a href="hello-scalate">hello to Scalate</a>.
      </body>
    </html>
  }

  post("/insert") {
    val key = params("key")
    val value = params("value")
    val newObj = MongoDBObject(key->value)
    mongoColl += newObj
  }

  get("/users") {
    mongoColl.find()
    for { x <- mongoColl } yield x
  }

}
```